# Uncaught TypeError: t(...).default is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to use react with midwayjs and webpack in typescript.
Browser throws the following exception:
**Uncaught TypeError: s.default is undefined**
It only returns this error in my browser console.
I don't understand why this error is shown.
Please help me check what might be wrong.
Here is my code:

package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@midwayjs/decorator": "^2.13.2",
        "@midwayjs/web": "^2.13.4",
        "chalk": "^4.1.2",
        "egg": "^2.32.0",
        "egg-webpack": "^5.0.1",
        "midway": "^2.13.4",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "tslib": "^2.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.3.6",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^6.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
        "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "midway-bin": "^1.20.3",
        "postcss": "^8.3.8",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
        "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.4",
        "webpack": "^5.56.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=local midway-bin dev --ts"
    },
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');
const { resolve } = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
    cache: {
        type: 'filesystem',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        demo: resolve(__dirname, './src/app/web/page/demo/app.tsx'),
    },
    externals: { React: 'React' },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        noParse: /react\.production\.min\.js$/,
        rules: [
            {
                include: [resolve(__dirname, './src/app/web')],
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [require('autoprefixer')],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                include: resolve(__dirname, './src/app/web'),
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: {
                            transpileOnly: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                '@babel/preset-env',
                                '@babel/preset-react',
                            ],
                            plugins: [
                                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                                [
                                    'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
                                    {
                                        mode: 'wrap',
                                        ignoreFilenames: ['node_modules'],
                                    },
                                ],
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                test: /\.js$/,
            }),
        ],
        runtimeChunk: true,
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            hidePathInfo: true,
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name]_[chunkhash].js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, './src/app/public'),
        pathinfo: false,
        publicPath: '/public',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            chunks: ['demo'],
            favicon: resolve(__dirname, './src/app/web/page/demo/blank.ico'),
            inject: 'body',
            filename: 'demo.html',
            template: resolve(__dirname, './src/app/web/page/demo/index.html'),
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name]_[contenthash].css',
        }),

        new ProgressBarPlugin({
            format:
                '  build [:bar] ' +
                chalk.green.bold(':percent') +
                ' (:elapsed seconds)',
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new WebpackManifestPlugin({
            clearConsole: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    stats: 'errors-only',
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ESNext"
        ],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ESNext",
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "webpack.config.js",
        "app.js"
    ]
}
```

app.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <p>demo</p>;
    }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: what is `<slot></slot>`?  can`t see it defined somewhere

Comment: Can you share the whole error message please?